# Socket hang up error Node js

Tags: nodejs, socket

Tengo un problema con los socket en nodejs. Realizo una petición a un API para obetener x cantidad de productos de una tienda. Después de obtener esta lista de productos, hago llamadas a un servicio externo, alojado en otro servidor, con las cuales obtengo el stock de todos los productos.

Esto es la parte en la que lanzo la petición al servicio externo con los datos de todos los productos:

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(productsFromAPI),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}
let response = await nodeFetch(`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15422/api/product/getStockFromBD`, options);
let responseJSON = await response.json();
return res.send({ result: responseJSON });
```

En el servicio externo recibo el array completo de productos, y voy recogiendolos de la base de datos:

```
    let finalStructure = [];
    await bluebird.mapSeries(productsFromAPI, async (pfa) => {
        let conn = await pool.getConnection();
        let sql = `select articulo, codigo_barras, stock_1 
            from alm 
            where entidad = :entidad and articulo like :articulo`;
        let objToSend = {
            entidad: 9,
            articulo: pfa.sku
        }
        let result = await conn.execute(sql, objToSend, {});
        if (result.rows != "") {
            let structure = appUtils.dbStructure(result.rows, result.metaData);
            let structureItem = { "ARTICULO": pfa.sku, "CODIGO_BARRAS": structure[0].CODIGO_BARRAS, "STOCK": 0 };
            structure.map((s) => {
                structureItem.STOCK = structureItem.STOCK + s.STOCK_1
            });
            finalStructure.push(structureItem)
        }
        await conn.close();
    });
    await pool.close();
    console.log(finalStructure);
    return res.send({result : finalStructure});
```

El error me lo arroja al tiempo. He probado a lanzar uno a uno los productos en vez de enviar el array completo, pero también recibo el error. Así que no lo acabo de entender. ¿Alguien tiene alguna forma de manejarlo? Gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo la solución. Al hacer lo siguiente:
El objeto Request, tiene un método con el nombre setTimeout.
Ejemplo:

```
async function funcionDePrueba(req, res, next) {
    try {
        req.setTimeout(1800000);
```

El parámetro indica la cantidad de milisegundos de timeout que tendrá la petición. En este caso serán 3 minutos.
Con esto he conseguido solucionar mi problema.

EDIT:
Además de lo que comento arriba, también se pueden usar algunas alternativas como instalar connect-timeout de express (en el caso de usar express).